# Imprimir código HTML

Tags: php, html, laravel

como puedo imprimir el código HTML en mi vista?

**Base de datos**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Vista**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como veran obtengo desde la base de datos un codigo html.  lo que necesito hacer es que se imprima sin las etiquetas en la vista.

```
  <h5 style="color: #3a3a3a;">Info Extra</h5>
                                <p>{{$evento->info}}</p>
                                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Cuando se usa contenido guardado de html, en cualquier lenguaje cuando se lo imprime, se lo trata como un texto y no como un grupo de etiquetas html, lo correcto es sacar el formato, de esta forma:

```html
<h5 style="color: #3a3a3a;">Info Extra</h5>
<p>{!! $evento->info !!}</p>
```